# Swift 2 Parse push notification

Tags: swift, parse-platform, push-notification, swift2

i'm trying to put push notification with parse with Swift 2 in Xcode 7.0 GM. the problem is that it connects but it doesn't show the push.. Do you know why ? Thank you in advance

Here it is my code.. of course i delete my Parse ID but in my project there is..i tried to use the code provided by Parse but i got errors.. so i used a project on Github but it's not working..

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    Parse.setApplicationId("here there is my ID of course")

    PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()

    let defaultACL = PFACL();

    // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this line.
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true)

    PFACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, withAccessForCurrentUser:true)

    if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.Background {
        // Track an app open here if we launch with a push, unless
        // "content_available" was used to trigger a background push (introduced in iOS 7).
        // In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double counting the app-open.

        let preBackgroundPush = !application.respondsToSelector("backgroundRefreshStatus")
        let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")
        var noPushPayload = false;
        if let options = launchOptions {
            noPushPayload = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil;
        }
        if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || noPushPayload) {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
        }
    }

    if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)



        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    } else {
        let types: UIRemoteNotificationType = [UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge, UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert, UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound]
        application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
    }


    return true



}



//--------------------------------------
// MARK: Push Notifications
//--------------------------------------

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    installation.saveInBackground()

    PFPush.subscribeToChannelInBackground("") { (succeeded, error) in
        if succeeded {
            print("ParseStarterProject successfully subscribed to push notifications on the broadcast channel.");
        } else {
            print("ParseStarterProject failed to subscribe to push notifications on the broadcast channel with error = %@.", error)
        }
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    if error.code == 3010 {
        print("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.")
    } else {
        print("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error)
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
    if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
        PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it connects" ? Did you set up your Push certificates (both debug and push) and upload them to Parse?

Comment: yes i think so.. i mean it print this print("ParseStarterProject successfully subscribed to push notifications on the broadcast channel.");

Comment: On Parse does it show that it sent the push / whether it was received?

Comment: now i see nothing :\

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it might be caused by one of the following:

1) **Make sure your running it on a real device, not the simulator.** Push notification are not supported on the simulator.

2) **Reinstall your app on your device.** This fixed my problem.  When it asks, allow it to send push notifications, obviously.

2) **Recreate your certificates and provisioning profile.** Click [here](https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications) to see how.

3) **Make sure your certificates are valid and installed.** Double click on on the downloaded provisioning profile to install it.

Also you might want to create a user and try it with that, not the automatic user.

**EDIT:**
I would suggest that you follow the quick start found [here](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/ios/swift/existing). I know that you will get errors, so here is how to fix them:

1) Delete `let userNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound` and delete the `let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)`.  Then type `let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)` in place of where you deleted the lines.

2) replace the `let types = UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound` line with `let types = UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge.union(UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert).union(UIRem‌​oteNotificationType.Sound)`

Comment: did all of this and didn't work.. do you know the code for swift 2?

Comment: the problem is only that it doesn't show the push.. it connects well i think

Comment: what do you mean by create a user?

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue.  i googled and experimented, and then it started working perfectly.  i think the code changes did not make a difference.  could parse of been having an issue? following is my code (from googling), and push notifications working:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        Parse.setApplicationId("***your id ***",
            clientKey: "*** your key ***")

        // Register for Push Notitications
        if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.Background {
            // Track an app open here if we launch with a push, unless
            // "content_available" was used to trigger a background push (introduced in iOS 7).
            // In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double counting the app-open.

            let preBackgroundPush = !application.respondsToSelector("backgroundRefreshStatus")
            let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")
            var pushPayload = false
            if let options = launchOptions {
                pushPayload = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil
            }
            if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || pushPayload) {
                PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
            }
        }

        /*
        if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
            let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        } else {
            let types : UIRemoteNotificationType = [.Badge, .Alert, .Sound]
            application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)

        }
        */

        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Sound, .Badge], categories: nil)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()

        // check if app opened because user tapped on notification
        if let launchOptions = launchOptions as? [String : AnyObject] {
            if let notificationDictionary = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? [NSObject : AnyObject] {
                self.application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: notificationDictionary)
            }
        }



        return true
    }


    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
        installation.saveInBackground()
    }


    /*
    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        installation["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
        installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
        installation.saveInBackground()
    }
    */

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
        if error.code == 3010 {
            print("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.")
        } else {
            print("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error)
        }
    }


    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
        if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
        }
    }
```